# How to calculate Gauss Manin connection?

Tags: complex-geometry, deformation-theory, hodge-theory, connections, specific-calculation

If $f:X\rightarrow B$ is a holomorphic family of compact complex manifold. Fix a $k$, then all the $H^k(X_t,\mathbb{C})$ is the same with respect to $t$. Say take a $d$-closed form  $\alpha\in H^k(X_t,\mathbb{C})$, how to  calculate $\nabla_\xi\alpha$, for some $\xi\in C^\infty(B,T^{1,0}B)$, or maybe at a point of B?

Comment: Who is $B$? Where does $t$ appear from? Why does $f$ disappear from the rest of the question?

Comment: Presumably $t \in B$ and $X_t = f^{-1}(t)$ is the fiber over $t$.